# How to instantiate nonpublic prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I instantiate prefabs by dragging them into a variable in the scene.  Here's the code:

```
public GameObject player1;

void Start()
{
    Instantiate(player1, spawn.position, spawn.rotation)
}
```

I don't want to drag and drop.  How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your prefab in the `Assets/Resources` folder.

Then you can find the prefab and then instantiate it.

```
private GameObject player1;

void Start()
{
    player1 = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Player1"), spawn.position, spawn.rotation) as GameObject;
}
```

`"Player1"` is the name of the prefab. You can call it what you want.

You can do this with any prefab or other data, such as textures. More information on `Resources.Load` on [Unity API](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html).