# Loading PreFab from c# in Unity

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, transform

I am trying to figure out how to instantiate an prefab from c# code and i have tried the following:

I have created an public Transform like so:

```
public Transform myItem;
```

I have then created an prefab and called it **myPrefab** and placed it in my Assets/Resources folder.

I then in start() call this:

```
myItem = Instantiate(Resources.Load("myPrefab")) as Transform;
```

When running the code the Transform stays empty?

What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to instantiate nonpublic prefab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502399/how-to-instantiate-nonpublic-prefab)

Comment: It would probably help in avoiding issues like this future to use hard casts (error-producing) instead of soft casts (null-producing).  If you wrote the above as `myItem = (Transform)Instantiate(Resources.Load("myPrefab"));`, Unity would tell you “`error CS0030: Cannot convert type \`UnityEngine.GameObject' to \`UnityEngine.Transform'`” and the issue with your `Instantiate()` API usage would be obvious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When objects are [**Instantiated**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) they become [**GameObjects**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html). Your code should look like this:

```
GameObject myItem = Instantiate(Resources.Load("myPrefab")) as GameObject;
```

If you want a [**Transform**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html) you can simply use the fact that all GameObjects have a transform component.

```
Transform t = myItem.transform.
```

---

Or if you really want to be a *badass*, you can do it all in one line:

```
Transform myItem = (Instantiate(Resources.Load("myPrefab")) as GameObject).transform;
```

Comment: Thanks, I love to be badass ;-)

Answer (score 5):

The prefab should be put into a GameObject instead of a Transform:

```
GameObject myItem = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("myPrefab"), typeof(GameObject));
```

Then you can access the Transform from the GameObject like this:

```
Transform transform = myItem.transform;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the prefabs path like that

```
GameObject mainObject = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("prefabs/" + "BaseMain"));
```